# How to give caption to image while posting to Facebook from Android

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am creating an Android application in which i have to share a post from my mobile to Facebook. I was using the following code, of old facebook sdk, initially which was working good (not complete code, just to tell):

```
private static void FeedDialog(final Activity pActivity, String description) 
{

  Bundle params = new Bundle();
  params.putString("name", 
  pActivity.getString(R.string.txt_fb_name_referral));
  params.putString("caption", 
  pActivity.getString(R.string.txt_fb_caption_referral));
  params.putString("description", description );
  params.putString("link", "http://www.icarpool.com/");
  params.putString("picture", ICarpoolConstants.FB_SHARE_IMAGE_URL);

  WebDialog feedDialog = (
new WebDialog.FeedDialogBuilder(pActivity,
  Session.getActiveSession(),
  params))
  .setOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener() {

   @Override
   public void onComplete(Bundle values,
     FacebookException error) {

   }

  })
  .build();
  feedDialog.show();
  }
```

Now as SDK is updated we have to share photos using SharePhoto class, and to share links ShareLinkContent. My requirement is to share a link with an image and a caption.

```
ShareLinkContent content = new ShareLinkContent.Builder()
                .setContentUrl(Uri.parse("http://instant.icarpool.com/images/sharereward.png"))
                .setContentTitle("Test Post")
                .setContentDescription("Successful post")
                .build();

        shareDialog.show(content);
```

the functions setContentTitle and setContentDescription are deprecated, what are replacements now for these methods. I have searched a lot on SO as well as their documentation. If anyone has an idea please guide through it. Thanks

Comment: If you share a URL, the title/caption, description and thumbnail will be taken from the Open Graph meta tags of that URL. Specifying these values dynamically at the point of sharing is not possible any more. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog#v2_9_90_day_deprecations

Comment: you can add a caption from this method .setQuote("caption goes here..") in ShareLinkContent. @HarryNaeem

Comment: @Sam yes i checked this method, its the sets the caption but it also shows that this post was shared as a quote on facebook.

Comment: and you can't add a caption of a user because it's violated privacy policy of user in Facebook official. check 2nd section : https://developers.facebook.com/policy

Comment: @Sam yes i have read it

Comment: @Harry.Naeem then cool and if you still want then make it custom without FB SDK.

Comment: Look at my answer in this question and check if it helps. https://stackoverflow.com/a/46459350/4107421